# Why is my regex returning uppercase when I want lowercase?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a function that takes in a string and returns the number of lowercase letters in a key/value object. I also want to exclude spaces.

```
function countLetters(str) {
  letterStorage = {}
  regex = /[a-z]/g
  
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] in letterStorage && str[i].search(regex)) {
      letterStorage[str[i]]++;
    } else if (str[i].search(regex)) {
      letterStorage[str[i]] = 1;
    }
  }
  return letterStorage;
}

console.log(countLetters('AAA BBB bbb ccc'))
```

countLetters() should return `{b: 3, c:3}` but instead it's returning `{A: 3, " ": 3, B: 3}`. I'm confused because I didn't use `i` in my regex either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string `search` method will return `-1` if not found. You're then checking `if(-1) {}` and `-1` actually evaluates to truthy. Since you're iterating through each character individually, you actually just want to check if the zeroth character matches, so you'll want something like `str[i].search(regex) === 0`.

```js
function countLetters(str) {
  letterStorage = {}
  regex = /[a-z]/g
  
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] in letterStorage && str[i].search(regex) === 0) {
      letterStorage[str[i]]++;
    } else if (str[i].search(regex) === 0) {
      letterStorage[str[i]] = 1;
    }
  }
  return letterStorage;
}

console.log(countLetters('AAA BBB bbb ccc'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to judge whether a string  matches the regex, you should use `test`, just like that `regex.test(str[i])`